# Django throwing django.core.exceptions.SynchronousOnlyOperation with SyncPlaywright module

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, async-await, playwright

I'm currently working on a Django project where I need to scrape data from a website using Playwright. However, I'm encountering an issue due to the asynchronous nature of Playwright conflicting with Django's synchronous request/response cycle although I am using the Playwright's SYNC api.

```py
def extract_fbvideo_from_url(url, mp4_filename):
    playwright = sync_playwright().start()
    browser = playwright.chromium.launch(headless=True, channel="msedge")
    page = browser.new_page()
    page.goto(url)
    page_source = page.content()
    base_url = extract_url_from_source(page_source)
    response= requests.get(base_url, headers=headers)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        # filename= f"media/{uuid4().__str__()}.mp4"
        with open(mp4_filename, "wb") as f:
            f.write(
                response.content
            )
        return mp4_filename
    print(f"Couldn't get fb video: [{url}]")
    return None
```

The response is sent successfully as required but I am getting following error afterwords:

```bash
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 196, in finish_response
    self.close()
  File "/home/ubuntu/Saas_transcription/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 118, in close
    super().close()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/wsgiref/simple_server.py", line 38, in close
    SimpleHandler.close(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 335, in close
    self.result.close()
  File "/home/ubuntu/Saas_transcription/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/http/response.py", line 292, in close
    signals.request_finished.send(sender=self._handler_class)
  File "/home/ubuntu/Saas_transcription/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 180, in send
    return [
  File "/home/ubuntu/Saas_transcription/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 181, in <listcomp>
    (receiver, receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named))
  File "/home/ubuntu/Saas_transcription/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 38, in close_old_connections
    conn.close_if_unusable_or_obsolete()
  File "/home/ubuntu/Saas_transcription/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 510, in close_if_unusable_or_obsolete
    if self.get_autocommit() != self.settings_dict['AUTOCOMMIT']:
  File "/home/ubuntu/Saas_transcription/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 389, in get_autocommit
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/home/ubuntu/Saas_transcription/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 31, in inner
    raise SynchronousOnlyOperation(message)
django.core.exceptions.SynchronousOnlyOperation: You cannot call this from an async context - use a thread or sync_to_async.
[12/Feb/2024 09:52:23] ERROR "django.server" "POST /backend/transcribe/facebook HTTP/1.1" 500 59
----------------------------------------
Exception occurred during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 38524)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 196, in finish_response
    self.close()
  File "/home/ubuntu/Saas_transcription/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 118, in close
    super().close()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/wsgiref/simple_server.py", line 38, in close
    SimpleHandler.close(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 335, in close
    self.result.close()
  File "/home/ubuntu/Saas_transcription/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/http/response.py", line 292, in close
    signals.request_finished.send(sender=self._handler_class)
  File "/home/ubuntu/Saas_transcription/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 180, in send
    return [
  File "/home/ubuntu/Saas_transcription/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 181, in <listcomp>
    (receiver, receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named))
  File "/home/ubuntu/Saas_transcription/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 38, in close_old_connections
    conn.close_if_unusable_or_obsolete()
  File "/home/ubuntu/Saas_transcription/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 510, in close_if_unusable_or_obsolete
    if self.get_autocommit() != self.settings_dict['AUTOCOMMIT']:
  File "/home/ubuntu/Saas_transcription/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 389, in get_autocommit
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/home/ubuntu/Saas_transcription/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 31, in inner
    raise SynchronousOnlyOperation(message)
django.core.exceptions.SynchronousOnlyOperation: You cannot call this from an async context - use a thread or sync_to_async.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/socketserver.py", line 683, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/socketserver.py", line 747, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/home/ubuntu/Saas_transcription/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 176, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "/home/ubuntu/Saas_transcription/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 201, in handle_one_request
    handler.run(self.server.get_app())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 145, in run
    self.handle_error()
  File "/home/ubuntu/Saas_transcription/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 123, in handle_error
    super().handle_error()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 382, in handle_error
    self.finish_response()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 184, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 288, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 345, in send_headers
    if not self.origin_server or self.client_is_modern():
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 358, in client_is_modern
    return self.environ['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].upper() != 'HTTP/0.9'
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
----------------------------------------
```